# Trying to set up a class thru .h and .cpp files -- why do I get these errors?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference

I'm using `g++` on Debian 8.2 Jessie.

I'm learning about classes in C++. I think I understand the basics, but not fully how to instantiate class objects with header files.

Here's `Movie.h`:

```
#ifndef MOVIE_H
#define MOVIE_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Movie
{
private:
    std::string     m_title;
    int             m_releaseYear;
    std::string     m_description;
public:
    Movie(std::string &title, int releaseYear, std::string &description);
    ~Movie()
    {
        std::cout << "\nDestructor called\n";
    }

    void        setMovieInfo(std::string &title, int releaseYear, std::string &description);

    std::string getTitle();
    int         getReleaseYear();
    std::string getDescription();
    void        printInfo();
};

#endif
```

Then there's `Movie.cpp`:

```
#include "Movie.h"

// Movie constructor
Movie::Movie(std::string &title, int releaseYear, std::string &description)
{
    setMovieInfo(std::string &title, int releaseYear, std::string &description);
}

// Movie mem function
void Movie::setMovieInfo(const std::string &title, const int releaseYear, const std::string &description)
{
    m_title=            title;
    m_releaseYear=      releaseYear;
    m_description=      description;
}

std::string Movie::getTitle()
{
    return m_title;
}

int Movie::getReleaseYear()
{
    return m_releaseYear;
}

std::string Movie::getDescription()
{
    return m_description;
}

void Movie::printInfo()
{
    std::cout << "Title: " << m_title << '\n';
    std::cout << "Year: " << m_releaseYear << '\n';
    std::cout << "Description" << m_description << '\n';
}
```

And `main.cpp`:

```
#include "Movie.h"

int main(){
    std::string     title;
    int             releaseYear;
    std::string     description;

    title=          "Blade Runner";
    releaseYear=    1982;
    description=    "Harrison Ford's character hunts a group of runaway four-year-olds.";

    Movie bladeRunner(title, releaseYear, description);
    bladeRunner.printInfo();

    return 0;
}
```

I ran `g++ -Wall Movie.cpp main.cpp -o main.sh && ./main.sh`, but got this output:

```
Movie.cpp: In constructor ‘Movie::Movie(std::string&, int, std::string&)’:
Movie.cpp:6:27: error: expected primary-expression before ‘&’ token
  setMovieInfo(std::string &title, int releaseYear, std::string &description);
                           ^
Movie.cpp:6:35: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
  setMovieInfo(std::string &title, int releaseYear, std::string &description);
                                   ^
Movie.cpp:6:64: error: expected primary-expression before ‘&’ token
  setMovieInfo(std::string &title, int releaseYear, std::string &description);
                                                                ^
Movie.cpp: At global scope:
Movie.cpp:10:6: error: prototype for ‘void Movie::setMovieInfo(const string&, int, const string&)’ does not match any in class ‘Movie’
 void Movie::setMovieInfo(const std::string &title, const int releaseYear, const std::string &description)
      ^
In file included from Movie.cpp:1:0:
Movie.h:20:8: error: candidate is: void Movie::setMovieInfo(std::string&, int, std::string&)
  void  setMovieInfo(std::string &title, int releaseYear, std::string &description);
        ^
```

Comment: May I ask: Why are `Movie::getDescription` and `Movie::printInfo` not defined in `Movie.cpp`?

Comment: @swinefish Typo. I'll update it

Comment: Did you make any changes in file other than `main.cpp`? That kind of error often means that the signature in `Movies.cpp` and `Movies.h` do not match

Comment: @swinefish The latest version of all three files is now in my question. As far as I can tell, I changed only `main.cpp`

Comment: The signatures for the declaration and definition of `Movie::setMovieInfo` do not match.

Comment: You need to compile `Movie.cpp` also, `g++ Movie.cpp main.cpp -o main`

Comment: As @Niall points out, in `Movies.h` you have `Movie(std::string title, int releaseYear, std::string description)` (no reference params) while in `Movies.cpp` you have `Movie::Movie(std::string &title, int releaseYear, std::string &description)` (reference params)

Comment: Also, when compiling it's often a good idea to set warnings: `g++ -Wall *.cpp`

Comment: The call to `setMovieInfo` in the constructor should simply be `setMovieInfo(title, releaseYear, description);`

Comment: @Niall Along with that, removing the `const` from each parameter of `Movie::setMovieInfo()` got the program working. Why does leaving in the `const` result in the same error?

Comment: Given the function signatures `void fn(const int&)` and `void fn(int&)`, the compiler is able to differentiate them based on the `const`, they are not the same function signatures. So in the class definition you declare the `setMovieInfo` with a signature, when you define it in the cpp file, you give it another signature - this is not allowed, the signatures need to be the same.

Comment: You mentioned in one of the edits that you are new to C++, consider getting a good book on it. There is a nice list of them here, http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/3747990

Comment: Nice, thanks for that great resource

Answer (score 1):

Reference parameters to functions can initially be a little confusing. While you define a function with

```
void foo(int& i){}
```

When you call the function, you do not need to pass a reference. So you would call

```
foo(x);
```

rather than

```
foo(&x);
```

It can initially be confusing. In your case, simply call

```
Movie bladeRunner(title, releaseYear, description);
```

Also, it's worth noting that in your code there is no reason to have the parameters to the constructor be reference parameters. It does reduce memory usage a little, but that really shouldn't be a concern when you're first trying to get your code working. So `Movie(std::string title, int releaseYear, std::string description)` would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The call to `setMovieInfo` in the constructor should simply be `setMovieInfo(title, releaseYear, description);`. As it was originally written it is one return type away from being a function declaration.

The signatures for the declaration and definition of `Movie::setMovieInfo` do not match, the `const` needs to be removed from the one, or added to the to the other.

Given the function signatures `void fn(const int&)` and `void fn(int&)`, the compiler is able to differentiate them based on the const, they are not the same function signatures. So in the class definition you declare the setMovieInfo with a signature, when you define it in the cpp file, you give it another signature - this is not allowed, the signatures need to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor has three parameters, reference to string, int and another reference to string. As the parameters for the string are references, you can either pass a pointer or the variable in the object instantiation.

For example, a reference can only be

```
int a;
int &b = a;
```

You have written something like

```
int &b = &a;
```

which is unacceptable.

You can either use two of the below while you instantiate the object

```
Movie bladeRunner(title, releaseYear, description);
```

or create a pointer for title and description and pass the pointer.

This is because only a pointer or a variable can be passed to a reference. Here, the constructor stores your parameters as reference to a reference for title and description. I see the same mistake in the function call of `setMovieInfo` inside constructor.

Also in your definition of constructor, you are calling `setMovieInfo`. You need not mention the types in the parameters of `setMovieInfo`as they are already declared in the constructor's parameters. There is also another problem. For the function declaration in Movie.h for`setMovieInfo` you have not used any const. Please remove the const in the function definition in Movie.cpp.

Correct these errors and your program will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

From all the suggestions, I've come up with this working code.

`Movie.h`:

```
#ifndef MOVIE_H
#define MOVIE_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Movie
{
private:
    std::string     m_title;
    int             m_releaseYear;
    std::string     m_description;
public:
    Movie(std::string &title, int releaseYear, std::string &description);
    ~Movie()
    {
        std::cout << "\nDestructor called\n";
    }

    void        setMovieInfo(std::string &title, int releaseYear, std::string &description);

    std::string getTitle();
    int         getReleaseYear();
    std::string getDescription();
    void        printInfo();
};

#endif
```

`Movie.cpp`:

```
#include "Movie.h"

// Movie constructor
Movie::Movie(std::string &title, int releaseYear, std::string &description)
{
    setMovieInfo(title, releaseYear, description);
}

// Movie mem function
void Movie::setMovieInfo(std::string &title, int releaseYear, std::string &description)
{
    m_title=            title;
    m_releaseYear=      releaseYear;
    m_description=      description;
}

std::string Movie::getTitle()
{
    return m_title;
}

int Movie::getReleaseYear()
{
    return m_releaseYear;
}

std::string Movie::getDescription()
{
    return m_description;
}

void Movie::printInfo()
{
    std::cout << "Title: " << m_title << '\n';
    std::cout << "Year: " << m_releaseYear << '\n';
    std::cout << "Description: " << m_description << '\n';
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "Movie.h"

int main(){
    std::string     title;
    int             releaseYear;
    std::string     description;

    title=          "Blade Runner";
    releaseYear=    1982;
    description=    "Harrison Ford's character hunts a group of runaway four-year-olds.";

    Movie bladeRunner(title, releaseYear, description);
    bladeRunner.printInfo();

    return 0;
}
```